# JavaScript compare, match, and assign object in in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having trouble assigning a value from my nested array.  The loop is moving through correctly and looks to initially make a comparison of the following arrays.

```
let searchSource = [ 'media', 'arts'];

let subscriberNodes = [
   {
      name: 'customer',
      nodes: [
         {source: 'media'},
      ]
   }
]
```

Unfortunately with the code below I am not filtering through the data.

```
 let violation = subscriberNodes
      .filter( v => v.nodes = v.nodes.filter(q => searchSource === q.source) );
```

The **searchName** and **q.source** compare on one phase of the break point in the debugger but as I click again

```
 q.source // 'EDW'  to undefined
```

I am not sure why I am seeing it compare the same values 2 times and why the second time **q.source**   is undefined. It seems like filters are running 2 times.

I tried this with find as well but errored out the same result on the filter

```
  let qualifierViolations = profilerNodes
        .find(item => item.nodes)
        .filter(value => value.source === smartSearch)
```

When using **.some** I found that everything was getting touched but nothing filtered

```
let qualifierViolations = subscriberNodes
        .filter( v => v.nodes.some(q => searchSource !== q.source) );
```

At this point I do not know what I am missing or how to fix it.  Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

let subscriberNodes = [
       {
          name: 'customer',
          nodes: [
             {source: 'media'},
          ]
       }
    ]

Comment: You talk about four different variables, two are never given any value in your code. I think there are just two relevant ones: one filter array, and one array to filter. Remove the rest or give additional info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want to filter out, but if you want to keep only the users that have `{source: 'media'}` or `{source: 'arts'}`, here's how you can do it :

```js
let searchSouce = ['media', 'arts'];

let subscriberNodes = [{
    name: 'customer1',
    nodes: [{
      source: 'media'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'customer2',
    nodes: [{
      source: 'arts'
    }, {
      source: 'something'
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'customer3',
    nodes: [{
      source: 'something else'
    }]
  }
]

let violation = subscriberNodes.filter(subscriber =>
  subscriber.nodes.filter(node => searchSouce.indexOf(node.source) !== -1).length
);


console.log(violation) // Keeps only customer 1 and 2
```

`nodes.filter` will keep the nodes that contain `{source: 'media'}` or `{source: 'arts'}`. So, getting the filtered `.length` will return `0` or greater, which will in turn decide whether the subscriber is eventually kept or not.